# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: in a JNI based project from github

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I am trying to check out the android project from here: https://github.com/zzugyl/webrtc-based-android-aecm

I simply downloaded the zip file and opened it in android studio. I have allowed android studio to download the build tools and gradle plugins needed by this project. To get it to compile I have changed the following:

In the module build.gradle file, line 28 has been changed to following:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
```

In AndroidManifest.xml,

```
android:minSdkVersion="19"
```

has been removed. The project now compiles properly, but I get an error as soon as I run it on the phone. Here is the error message in Android Studio "Run" tab:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.android.webrtc.audio, PID: 19487
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.android.webrtc.audio-IxCJloiMuEWVZONHH243RA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.android.webrtc.audio-IxCJloiMuEWVZONHH243RA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libwebrtc_aecm.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1011)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1657)
        at com.android.webrtc.audio.MobileAEC.<clinit>(MobileAEC.java:47)
        at com.billhoo.android.aec.demo.DemoActivity.doAECM(DemoActivity.java:53)
        at com.billhoo.android.aec.demo.DemoActivity.onCreate(DemoActivity.java:44)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7183)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3032)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

The main point of error is line 47 in MobileAEC.java:

```
System.loadLibrary("webrtc_aecm");
```

I think it's saying it cannot find webrtc_aecm library file, but if I look at the project folders there is a `libwebrtc_aecm.so` file in `\app\src\main\jniLibs\armeabi`.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: The runtime linker is looking for an arm64-v8a library (i.e. a library for 64-bit ARMv8). But you only have an armeabi library (i.e. for 32-bit ARMv5). So that isn't going to work. I suggest you look for an alternative solution, since the project you linked to appears to be abandoned.

Comment: @Micheal is there any way to make it work with the 32 bit library?

Comment: You might be able to make your app 32-bit only, by making sure that you build/package all other native libraries only for `armeabi`. But you won't be able to publish such an app on Google Play.

Comment: @Michael is that something I need to change in my Android Studio settings? I have not added any other native libraries to this project, my project structure is exactly same as the github link, except for the modifications I made mentioned in the question

Comment: Looking at that project, it seems like the source code for the library is available. So it's unclear to me why it includes a prebuilt .so for `armeabi`. Anyway, see https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code